# How can I modify Firebase Database Rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

These rules work fine, but I also want to give Owners the ability to read Residents data. How do I rewrite the rule?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Owners": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
     "Residents": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give owners access to any residents data:

```
"Residents": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid || root.child('Owners').child(auth.uid).exists()",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

Notes:

- It allows all owners to see all residents. If you want more tight control over what owners can see what residents, you'll need to adapt the rules further.
- While each owner can see each resident, they can't get a list of residents. If that is requires, you need to grant them access on `/Residents`.